# response time values in aggregate report does not make sense in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I did a run with 400 Vus with following settings:

-> A Transaction controller as "Launch" with 1 request under it.The option to include timer & pre-post processor was disabled.

The 90%tile response time in aggregate report shows 8.9 sec for the request and 65 sec for the Launch transaction.

So,I am not getting as how the complete transaction takes 65 sec while the request takes around 9 secs

Answer (score 0):

Putting just 1 request under Transaction Controller does no make any sense as the values from the request and from Transaction Controller will be the same.

The whole idea of the Transaction Controller is getting view of how long request sequence took, i.e. if you have end-to-end scenario consisting from several individual requests you might be interested in how long did it take to execute them all.

See [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) guide for more details on Transaction Controller use cases and clarification on configuration options.

If you have only one request under Transaction Controller and still obtain different results for the request itself and for the transaction it may indicate resource lack on JMeter side, i.e. load generator machine is short on RAM or CPU or you have memory-intensive listener enabled. See [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/) for a checklist and configure your JMeter accordingly.

Comment: I am aware of the Tuning Tips and had no listener enabled. It could be due to resource limitations but since I am using a new system with 4 GB RAM and heap size increased, I am finding it difficult to  understand if it still find resources to be limited.
<br/>
Also the response time of opening a particular page doesn't match to the one noted while manual browsing during the load Execution i.e. Jmeter shows significant increased in time while the time noted is fairly 1/6th of jmeter's results.